# Python: How to add a list into a class and append it

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

I am trying to add a class `Department` and in this class, "courses" is supposed to be a list that I can add to with the add_course function. Is there a way to tell python that "courses" is a list and then use `.append` to add new courses to this list?

```
class Department:
    def __init__(self, name, code, courses):
        self.name = name
        self.code = code
        self.courses = courses
        courses.tolist()

    def add_course(self, course): 
        self.course = course
        courses.append(course)
```

Comment: Python uses duck-typing. You don't need the `.tolist()` call. Any object which has the `.append` method will work with your code. However you may want to look at type hints to help with linting & bug fixing.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you will always be passing in courses, you could try this:

```
class Department:
    def __init__(self, name, code, courses=None):
        self.name = name
        self.code = code
        if isinstance(courses, list):
            self.courses = courses
        elif courses is None:
            self.courses = []
        else:
            raise TypeError

    def add_course(self, course): 
        self.courses.append(course)
```